# Violation of the Permissions policy in google play

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, manifest, android-permissions

Our app was currently removed from google play for having the SMS permission. We already removed the permission and uploaded a new apk but the status of the project is still removed. Do we have to wait for them to review, it or is there any other necessary steps/action needed for the project to be back on Google Play?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Fillup google docs for permission.
2. Make sure your SMS permission is given in manifest and give the pop up in user level.
3. Contact google developers as soon as possible.

[See this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303)

Comment: this doesn't guarantee that they will accept your application.

Answer (score 2):

May be any of the **3rd party library** you are using in your project is already using those permissions. And when you build your project it merged all the **AndroidManifest** file in a single **Merged Manifest** file. This is the reason you are getting this warning because your final manifest has any of those permission(s).

***Solution 1:***  After build your project,

- Open your project's **AndroidManifest** file.
- Open the **Merged Manifest** tab in the bottom.
- Search for any of those permission. (example- **READ_SMS**)
- If you get any, now it's time to remove them. Check the example

**Example:** If you see **READ_SMS** permission in **Merged Manifest** file, so now open your project's **AndroidManifest** file and add the line written below to remove that permission from your project-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" tools:node="remove" />
```

Add the above permission line in your **AndroidManifest** file, and that's it. It will remove the Permission from the Merged Manifest file and your issue will be resolved.

**AndroidManifest file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.myapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" tools:node="remove" />

    <application
        android:name=".MyApp"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup">

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

***Solution 2:***  Replace/Remove those 3rd Party library which are using these permissions.

***Solution 3:***  For safe side you can add these lines in your **AndroidManifest** file.

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"
    tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"
    tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"
    tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"
    tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH"
    tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS"
    tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"
    tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG"
    tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"
    tools:node="remove" />
```

these lines will remove all the restricted permission(s) according to [Permission Policy](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/permissions/) if any used.

Hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The issue happened with our apk as well, we removed the alpha,beta and internal test channel apks with updated apks without any violation of policy and they restored the production apk for us.